# Java Combinatorics using Memoization/Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, memoization

I'm making a program that gives the amount of possible combinations given two numbers, like N choose K. I have a recursive solution that is as follows:

```
public static int combinations(int group, int members) {
    if (members == 1) {
        return group;
    }
    else if (members == group) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return(combinations(group - 1, members - 1) + 
                combinations(group - 1, members));
    }
}
```

This one works, but I need to use memoization to improve time complexity and speed it up for larger numbers and I'm not sure how to go about it. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Going by the formula for  `n choose k = ( n - 1 choose k - 1)  + ( n-1 choose k )`
the bottom up dynamic programming approach would be:

```
dp[n][k] = dp[n-1][k-1] + dp[n-1][k] if n > k 
else if n == k
dp[n][k] = 1
else
dp[n][k] = 0
```

start from `n = 1` and `k = 1`

```
dp[1][1] = 1; dp[1][0] = 1;
```

and then fill a two dimensional array till `dp[n][k]`

It could also be done with memoization as in your case. Your method could be changed to :

```
int[][] dp = new int[group][members];

public static int combinations(int group, int members, int[][] dp ) {

    if (members == 1) {
        return group;
    } else if (members == group) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ( dp[group][members] != 0 ) {
       return dp[group][members];
    }

    int first = 0, second = 0;
    if ( members <= group - 1) {
      first = combinations( group - 1, members - 1, dp );
      second = combinations( group - 1, members );
    } else if ( members - 1 <= group - 1 ) {
      first = combinations( group - 1, members - 1, dp );
    }
    dp[group][members] = first + second;

    return dp[group][members];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do caching, which comes with the great price of memory usage.

```
public static int combinations(int group, int members) {
    if (members > group - members) {
        members = group - members; // 21 choose 17 is same as 21 choose 4
    }

    final int[][] cache = new int[group][members];
    return combinations(group, members, cache);
}
private static int combinations(int group, int members, int[][] cache) {
    if (cache[group - 1][members - 1] > 0) {
        return cache[group - 1][members - 1];
    }
    else if (members == 1) {
        cache[group - 1][members - 1] = group;
        return group;
    }
    else if (members == group) {
        cache[group - 1][members - 1] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return (combinations(group - 1, members - 1, cache) + combinations(group - 1, members, cache));
    }
}
```

I did some quick test (non-professional benchmarks) and found that the original method takes half the time of the caching method. Looks like all these read/writes to the array cache is slowing things down drastically.

The other way is to change the whole formula.

```
public static int combinations(int group, int members) {
    if (members > group - members) {
        members = group - members;
    }

    int answer = 1;
    for (int i = group; i > group - members; i--) {
        answer *= i;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= members; i++) {
        answer /= i;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Again, I tested the new method with the original (which I made them use `BigInteger` for the test), and the new method is incredibly faster (26 seconds for original method vs 0.00 seconds for the latter for 35 choose 15).

To add on a bit, I think the time complexity for using recursive call is `O((group)(log members))`, while using the new formula is simply `O(members)`.